# Session Generation with Redis+PHP and load balancing

Tags: php, nginx, session, redis, load-balancing

I have two servers running PHP (Apache), and both are load balanced by NGINX.

To manage the sessions I decided to use Redis. Both in the application (CodeIgniter 3) and in the php.ini settings I configured redis as the session server.

I have two servers running PHP, and both are NGINX balanced.

To manage the sessions I decided to use Redis. Both in the application (CodeIgniter) and in the php.ini settings I configured redis as the session server.

However, have the following concern: Is there a risk that the two PHP servers generate the same session identifier for different people? And risk user B accessing user A's session?

If yes, how to fix it?
Or at the time of session_start PHP already sees if this session_id exists and does not create an equal one.

Comment: Since somewhere in 5.x PHP started generating session IDs with a cryptographically-safe RNG, and of sufficient length that it is incredibly unlikely that they will ever collide.

Comment: Also if you didn't see it yet, there is [Securing Session INI Settings](https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.security.ini.php) in the PHP manual, next to all the session directives. There you should find "hot to fix it". And if session_start() is called and the session_id() exists, it will enter the existing session, always. That's how it works and why it's called a session ID.